# Determining whether series diverges or converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \left(\frac{1-n}{2+3n} \right)^n$$

The question is to determine whether the series converges or diverges. I tried to distribute the power $n$ to the numerator and the denominator then test both using $limits$. The denominator goes $\infty$ but unsure how to take care of the top using $limits$. Any suggestions?

Comment: look up the root test

Comment: or try the ratio test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long division tells us that
$$
\frac{1-n}{2+3n} = \frac{-1} 3 \left( 1 - \frac 5 {2+3n} \right).
$$

So we have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{-1} 3\right)^n \left( 1 - \frac 5 {2+3n} \right)^n.
$$

The factor $\displaystyle \left( 1 - \frac 5 {2+3n} \right)^n$ converges to a constant involving $e$ (start with $\left( 1 + \frac a n\right)^n\to e^a$ and do a bit of algebra).  Hence the absolute values of the terms are bounded above by
$$
C \left( \frac 1 3 \right)^n.
$$